# three.js with ascii effect doesn't save with html2canvas

Tags: three.js, html2canvas

I have a site made with three.js and ascii effect renderer (constantly moving image, which can be controlled with mouse interaction), and want to save the generated image of whole generated body with html2canvas, but it doesn't work, this is the code and the error message

```
    const animationCanvas = document.body;
    const saveButton = document.getElementById("savelink");
    let dataURL = null

    saveButton.addEventListener("click", generateImage);

    // Generate image
    async function generateImage() {
        await window.html2canvas(animationCanvas).then(canvas => {
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        }).then( () => {
            downloadImage(dataURL, 'picture.jpeg');
        } ).then(() => location.reload() );
    }
    // Download image
    function downloadImage(data, filename = 'untitled.jpeg') {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
```

[image]

If I try to save some individual div of the page, it works without problems. Any idea what can be wrong?

EDIT: as suggested by @2pha, this is the error when using unminified html2canvas

```
length-percentage.ts:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at getAbsoluteValue (length-percentage.ts:38)
    at getAbsoluteValueForTuple (length-percentage.ts:35)
    at calculateBackgroundRendering (background.ts:63)
    at canvas-renderer.ts:556
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:82)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:68)
getAbsoluteValue    @   length-percentage.ts:38
getAbsoluteValueForTuple    @   length-percentage.ts:35
calculateBackgroundRendering    @   background.ts:63
(anonymous) @   canvas-renderer.ts:556
step    @   tslib.es6.js:97
(anonymous) @   tslib.es6.js:78
step    @   tslib.es6.js:82
(anonymous) @   tslib.es6.js:78
fulfilled   @   tslib.es6.js:68
async function (async)      
generateImage   @   index.html:432
```

Comment: try using the unminified html2canvas js and the error will give you the line number to check

Comment: @2pha thanks, I modified the issue description, seems it is stuck at `at getAbsoluteValue (length-percentage.ts:35)` that it is undefined. any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of checks I found out that a select/option element was making this error, so I had to remove it before the html2canvas generating

```
<select id="choose">
            <option value="choice1" selected="selected">choice1</option>
            <option value="choice2">choice2</option>
            <option value="choice3">choice3</option>
            <option value="choice4">choice4</option>
        </select>
```

With this style:

```
select {
...
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='black'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>") no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px;
...
}
```

The svg made the mess. So rule-of-thumb: no svg for html2canvas generation...